# how to fix template parse error in angular?

Tags: angular

I have used this library for my ionic project:

Error: Template parse errors:

> Can't bind to 'topOrg' since it isn't a known property of 'ng2-org-chart'.

1. If `'ng2-org-chart'` is an Angular component and it has `'topOrg'` input, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If `'ng2-org-chart'` is a Web Component then add `'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA'` to the `'@NgModule.schemas'` of this component to suppress this message.
3. To allow any property add `'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA'` to the `'@NgModule.schemas'` of this component.

```
<ion-content padding>

  <ng2-org-chart [ERROR ->][topOrg]="topOrg"></ng2-org-chart>

</ion-content>
```

from `ng:///AppModule/LineagePage.html@28:17`

`'ng2-org-chart'` is not a known element:

1. If `'ng2-org-chart'` is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If `'ng2-org-chart'` is a Web Component then add `'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA'` to the `'@NgModule.schemas'` of this component to suppress this message.

```
<ion-content padding>

  [ERROR ->]<ng2-org-chart [topOrg]="topOrg"></ng2-org-chart>

</ion-content>
```

from `ng:///AppModule/LineagePage.html@28:2`

Answer (score 0):

`'import { OrgChartModule } from 'ng2-org-chart';` statement in corresponding module should fix it and also change [topOrg] to [topEmployee] then verify. updated 
stackbitz - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-g6ypks?file=src/app/app.component.html
(if you try to change topEmployee to toOrg where input is getting passed it doesnt work as you are using some existing npm package where input is being passed as 'topEmployee')

Comment: is anyone there could help me in organizational chart in a ionic project. Or suggest alternative for this ng2-org-chart